# UITableViewCell automatically appearing by an action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I thought about, but I prefer ask someone about how to automatically add a `UITableViewCell` to its specific `UITableView` when an event is occurring.

For example to be more precise: When user tap a button like "add a new contact to my address book" and at that point a new `UITableViewCell` (we will take for example: a `UITableViewCell` custom class called: `ContactCell`) is appearing.

How to do this properly ?

Answer (score 2):

If the new contact cell you would like to add looks identical in layout to the existing contact cells, then you update the data source and reload the table.  I do not know what your data source looks like so I cannot provide code, but perhaps there is a default contact with "Last Name, First" as the name of the person.  After the data source has been updated, call `[self.tableView reloadData];` and your new cell will appear in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is something like this?

```
- (void)likeAction:(id)sender
 {
    NSLog(@"like button tapped");
    // add data to your address book
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation];
    [tableView endUpdates];
 }
```

adding data to your dataSource (address book) is important.. just dont forget..